# Documenting a private struct inside a class

Tags: c++, doxygen

At the moment, I have:

```
/// @brief Random class.
class Foo {
    /// @brief A private embedded struct of Foo.
    struct Bar {
        /// @brief Some value.
        int x;
    }
}
```

My Doxygen output lists `Bar` as a 'data structure' on `Foo`'s reference page, but nowhere can I find the documentation for `x`. `Bar` is not hyperlinked and doesn't seem to appear on the global data structures page. Are there any hoops I have to jump through, or is it down to my Doxyfile options?

(I'm creating my output with Doxygen 1.7.1, if that makes a difference. The output is being generated on a shared server, so I don't have much of an option to change that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` setting in `Doxyfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a comment on the same line.

```
    int x; ///< Some value.
```

But it should be the same...